# How can I detect number of hops being used?

Tags: configuration

```
ExcludeSingleHopRelays 0
AllowSingleHopCircuits 1
AllowSingleHopExits 1
```

Does this configuration force Tor to behave just like common proxy without anonymity? How can I detect if Tor uses only one hop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tor configuration is set either by:

- the client (i.e. the Tor client running on your machine), or
- the server (i.e. the Tor relay).

---

### Client-side configuration

These options are set by the user - i.e. *you* - in the `.torrc` file. This is under *your* control. If you can't remember if you have set these options in the past, check your `.torrc`.

`ExcludeSingleHopRelays` is a configuration option for **clients**. By default this is set to `1` (i.e. True) to prevent single-hop circuits from being used.

`AllowSingleHopCircuits` is also a configuration option for **clients**. By default it's set to '0' to prevent single-hop circuits from being used.

### Server-side configuration

These options are *not* set by you, but by the person running the Tor relay.

`AllowSingleHopExits` is a configuration option for **servers**. It allows the relay to be the sole relay in a single-hop circuit. By default it is `0` (i.e. False).

---

> Is this config forces Tor to behave just like common proxy without
>   anonymity? How can i detect, if tor uses only 1 hop?

These settings would allow you to use a single-hop circuit, but I don't believe they *force* a single-hop circuit. (I've checked by setting the client-side options in my config file, navigating to a page using the Tor Browser, and checking the drop-down Tor Circuit box. It has a normal 3-hop circuit.)

> without anonymity?

Not necessarily. The destination site will still see the IP address of the exit node (i.e. the only node in your circuit). They won't see your *original* IP address. However, the single relay in your circuit *can* see your original IP address, so you are less anonymous to the that node than you would be if you used a normal 3-hop circuit.

> How can i detect, if tor uses only 1 hop?

You will know whether you have the client-side config options set in your `.torrc`, because *you* will have set them. At least with the Tor Browser you can check the hop count using the drop-down Tor Circuit box (by clicking on the onion icon).